# how to scroll till the top row when the bottom row is focused in gridlayoutmanager

Tags: android, row, gridlayoutmanager

i have a vertical grid view where it should show 3.5 rows which means 4 th row half should be visible at once.

once user comes to the 4th row then it should show 2nd row , 3rd row, 4th row and half of 5th row.

But now i was able to see quater of 1st row

i have tried gridlayout manager and snap helper but no use

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the scrolling behavior by manipulating the RecyclerView position programmatically. You can scroll to the top row when the bottom row is focused by listening to scroll events and taking action based on the visible items.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        // Check if the last visible item is the 4th row (or close to it).
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = gridLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        
        // Calculate the total number of rows you want to be visible.
        int totalVisibleRows = 3; // 3.5 rows

        if (lastVisibleItemPosition >= totalVisibleRows) {
            // Scroll to the top of the 2nd row.
            gridLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(1, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

When the user scrolls, we check if the last visible item is beyond the 4th row. If it is, we programmatically scroll to the top of the 2nd row.

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, numberOfColumns);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Good Luck.